# How to dynamically allocate and reallocate char arrays in C program?

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I'm writing a card game program and currently, I'm trying to create global `char*` arrays to represent a player 1 hand and a player 2 hand. I want to use `malloc` if the arrays have not been initialized yet and `realloc` later in the game in order to deal into them again. I have a function called `dealCards` which takes the deck of cards and the number to deal out as arguments. Within I want to be able to reallocate memory to the player arrays with each call depending on the number of cards to deal. So far I tried to test if the arrays were `NULL` and to use `malloc` and if not, use `realloc`, but I got errors of my conditions always equalling false and true therefore the would not test correctly. My current approach which still isn't working is to `malloc` a single char in the first index of each array, then reallocate in my function. But this is returning an error that reallocation has not occurred. So essentially how can I dynamically create two `char*` arrays, and then reallocate as needed on a function call?

Deal cards function

```
int dealCards(char *(*deck)[13], int numCardsToDeal)
{

    char *player1Hand = realloc(player1Hand, numCardsToDeal / 2 * (4 * sizeof(char)));
    char *player2Hand = realloc(player2Hand, numCardsToDeal / 2 * (4 * sizeof(char)));

    //If number of cards passed in is greater than whats left in deck
    if (numCardsToDeal > cardsRemaining)
    {
        printf("Number of cards to deal exceeds remaining deck. Remaining deck will be dealt.");
        numCardsToDeal = cardsRemaining;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numCardsToDeal;)
    {
        player1Hand[i] = *deck[placeInDeck / 13][i];
        printf("%c", player1Hand[i]);
        i++;
        if (i == numCardsToDeal)
        {
            break;
        }
        player2Hand[i] = *deck[placeInDeck / 13][i];
        printf("%c", player2Hand[i]);
        i++;
    }

    return numCardsToDeal;
}
```

My current attempt at initially using malloc

```
char **player1Hand;
char **player2Hand;

void initializePlayers(void)
{
    char **player1Hand = malloc(sizeof(*player1Hand));
    char **player2Hand = malloc(sizeof(*player2Hand));

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        player1Hand[i] = malloc(sizeof(char));
        player2Hand[i] = malloc(sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

If any more info is needed please let me know, thanks.

Comment: Do you *need* to constantly resize the arrays? You could work with fixed size arrays that can contain the maximum number of cards a player can hold. You'll need to know how many cards the player holds, either way.

Comment: @WeatherVane Technically I could, I just wanted to keep memory use in mind and not use more than needed at any given time.

Comment: Does that mean you might not have enough memory for a player holding the maximum possible cards that the game rules permit?

Comment: @WeatherVane no probably not, each player will at most have 20 cards, I was just trying to practice best practices